# is Bind[(exclude ..)] removed from ASP Core?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to exclude some properties from binding when getting values from View 
I am using at the action level : Bind exclude as the following :

1. [image]

I need this property to sent to the view (as readonly) but not allowing the user to update the value or even hacker try to inject value ....
the question:is exclude no longer available  in ASP MVC Core ? is there any other way ? 
again I know I can exclude the Property at Model level (using neverbind) but I want only send the value to the view , but not receive them back !

Comment: I guess you could use `Bind(include: ... )` and list the properties you do want to bind, but if you have too many properties that could be annoying. Could be a sign towards using different view models for read and write operations?

Answer (score 1):

There are some discussion in  : https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4857 :

> > Yup. I wanted a strict binder where you had to specify everything, but apparently this was too mean. Of course really everything should be view model based.
> >
> > How would you feel about throwing if someone bound to a class used in a dbcontext?

So currently you may need to use include for security concern .