# how to exclude an attribute using model binding in a controller in asp.net core web api

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, model-binding

Hi im tyring to exlude one property from my model when it reaches my action in the controller (Web API),

i tried `[Bind(Exclude ="something")]` but it seems that its not apart of .net core api

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55665609/2410655

Comment: iirc `[Bind]` only works for multipart/form (MVC actions), not WebAPi which uses json/xml payloads. But if you use proper ViewModel classes (they should only contain values required for a specific action), excluding isn't necessary at all

Answer (score 7):

If you are on ASP.NET Core, Use the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.BindNeverAttribute` attribute (`[BindNever]`).

```
public class ExampleViewModel
{
    // ResponseMessage will not participate in model binding.

    [BindNever]
    public string ResponseMessage { get; set; }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.bindneverattribute?view=aspnetcore-5.0

"Indicates that a property should be excluded from model binding. When applied to a property, the model binding system excludes that property. When applied to a type, the model binding system excludes all properties that type defines."

Answer (score 5):

`[Bind]` attribute does not work for the web api if you receive the model as json, try to use `[JsonIgnore]` on the model properties which need to be excluded:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Student([FromBody]MyModel model)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ViewModel and bind your view with model binder although if your field which you want to exclude if not null then your model state validation couldn't fail